# Change color of server in pgadmin

Tags: pgadmin-4

How do I change these colors in pgadmin? Clicking the color won't change or prompt a rgb seleciton. I did this on setup by accident, but it bothers me a lot now.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to disconnect from the server first and then you can click on the color. A prompt will open and from there you can select your desired color.

[image]

[image]